# STRB works, unless target address gets shifted

Tags: c, assembly, arm, byte

I'm trying to use ARM assembly to insert one string into another, however my code would always return an empty string to the C program calling the assembly program. I believe I have narrowed down my issue to the STRB instruction. Below is my code with most irrelevant code removed. The important part to look at is in the "test" block.

```
        .global ins
ins:
        stmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
        mov     v1, a1          @ save pointer to 1st string
        mov     v2, a2          @ save pointer to 2nd string
        bl      strlen          @ find out length
        mov     v3, a1          @ save string1 length
        mov     a1, v2          @ recover pointer to string 2
        bl      strlen          @ length of string 2
        add     a1, a1, v3      @ total length
        add     a1, a1, #1      @ add one for null byte
        bl      malloc
        add     a3, a3, #1

test:
        ldrb    v3, [v1], #1
        strb    v3, [a1], #1
        ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
exit:
        .end
```

v1 and v2 hold strings 1 and 2. When I have the test block written as:

```
test:
        ldrb    v3, [v1], #1
        strb    v3, [a1], #1
        ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
```

then the program returns an empty string. However, if I have it written as:

```
test:
        ldrb    v3, [v1], #1
        strb    v3, [a1]
        ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
```

it successfully returns the first character in string 1. Obviously, this is not sufficient to build a new string, as I'm not performing an offset on a1.

Does anyone know what is causing the string to be returned as empty? I honestly have no idea what the issue may be after several hours of experimenting and researching.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `a1` is returned to the C function calling your assembler routine. You need to return the address of the start of the string, but if you increment `a1` while writing the string you will return the address of the end of the string instead.

If you use another register for storing the current address that you are writing to then the start address will still be in `a1` when you return. e.g:

```
test:
    mov     v4, a1          @ copy address of new string to v4
    ldrb    v3, [v1], #1
    strb    v3, [v4], #1    @ increment v4, the start of string
                            @ will still be in a1
    ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought of this when I was trying to figure this out on my own, but I must've tried it backwards (ie. saved the address of a1 in another register, then tried to restore the original address into a1. Didn't seem to work.)

Should be well on my way to finishing this up now, thank you!

Comment: That's odd, I would have expected that way to work also